# Add to Shapes a ContextMenu JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx-8, contextmenu

I want to add a context menu to the circle when i right click it:

```
public void ContMen(Stage stage) {

Group root = new Group();
Circle c=new Circle(220,125,10);
c.setFill(Color.BROWN);

root.getChildren().add(c);
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 250);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
}
```

how can i add it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty example of adding a context menue to a circle.

```
public class ContextMenuDemo extends Application {

    private StackPane root;

    private Circle circle;

    private ContextMenu contextMenu;

    private MenuItem deleteItem;

    public ContextMenuDemo() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        root = new StackPane();

        circle = new Circle(200, 200, 100, Color.RED);
        circle.setOnMousePressed(this::handleMousePressed);

        root.getChildren().add(circle);

        contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        deleteItem = new MenuItem("Delete");
        deleteItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                root.getChildren().remove(circle);
            }
        });
        contextMenu.getItems().add(deleteItem);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();        
    }

    protected void handleMousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
            contextMenu.show((Node)e.getSource(), Side.RIGHT, 5, 5);
            e.consume();
        }
    }

}
```